# Reset modal window when closed

Tags: javascript, wordpress, modal-dialog

I'm using wordpress with visual composer and I have built this demo popup example https://www.air8cushion.com/index.php/popup-test/ when I click on "More Info" button the popup shows up. However when I scroll content inside of it, and close the modal window, and again click on "More Info" I need to reset the content to appear from the top again.

I know its possible to do it with JS but I had fails many times to make it work. Most of examples of similar things online are mostly for Bootstrap and  none of them worked for me.

Thanks.

Comment: it seems you are using height to show and hide popup (in your case you are using div instead of popup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this on click of the close button of your popup

this function will scroll viewport of the popup div to top when clicked

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.vc_general',function(){
   var myDiv = document.getElementById('myNav');
   myDiv.scrollTop = 0;
});
```

".vc_general" is one of the class in your close button. You can add an extra class if you think it will affect the other functionality.

Comment: perfect, works like a charm. Another question, how do I also prevent here once I scroll the model window content, that the content behind the modal is not scrollable once I get to end of modal window?

Comment: is it possible to customize that script to add css class to body so its not scrollable once modal window showsup?